# How to implement a protocol

Tags: c#, java, c++, protocols

are there any open source desktop sharing protocols? if so, what are they? can anybody tell me the things i would know in order to implement a protocol e.g if i want to write a desktop sharing protocol what are the things i need to know and from where i should begin.(preferred languages Java, C++ and C#)

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by a "desktop sharing protocol"..? For example, do you mean something along the lines of Microsofts Remote Desktop (RDP) or XWindows?

Comment: the protocols use with TeamViewer, VNC...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RFB is the protocol used in VNC applications, and it is an open specification.

A protocol is just a language that networked applications 'agree' to speak. That is to say, because both ends of the connection are speaking the same language (meaning they know what bytes mean what in the communication) they are capable of sending meaningful information to one another and interpreting the information they receive.

Therefore, the first thing you should do before implementing a protocol is to learn and understand it. Often (and always in the case of open specifications) there will be a document that explains the protocol and all the ins and outs. For example, the specification for the RFB protocol can be found [here](http://www.realvnc.com/docs/rfbproto.pdf).

Read it and implement a program that can understand RFB and you will have created an RFB implementation.

As for the preferred language bit: a protocol doesn't stipulate what language the protocol is implemented in, just the way that communication takes place, so you can implement it in whatever language you wish.

Comment: The protocol might not mandate it, but there are other practical concerns: a remote desktop _server_ must capture a complete desktop, which might not be possible in all languages.

Answer (score 2):

The VNC protocol(*) has many open source implementations, and actually the Microsoft RDP protocol has also a few open source implementations.

Protocols cannot be "open source" actually - they can be "open" as in "the specifications are publicly available for free" and they can be "open source compatible" as in "if you implement the protocol in an open source program we won't sue your a$$ off", but usually "open source" means that you can change the source and changing a protocol would not really be beneficial because you then won't be able to inter-operate, right?

For a Microsoft RDP open source client look at [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org) and the [xrdp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xrdp/) project is implementing the server side on top of the X11 display protocol. VNC implementations are a dime a dozen, but for starters you might want to look at [tightvnc](http://www.tightvnc.com) or [realvnc](http://www.realvnc.com)

(*) Actually RFB is the protocol used in VNC compatible clients, as noted by Paul Ruane, and VNC is the name of the original software suite and is also used as the generic term for a software that implements RFB and employs the same networking semantics as the original VNC client.